# How do I get the total cost of sales of each item within a loop?

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, sum, random

Within this while loop, there are 4 items that can be picked. Coffee (1), Latte (2), Cappuccino (3), and Espresso (4). The simulation picks a bunch of random numbers in to fill in each customer's order and quantity, and then it calculates the total cost for each customer. Now I have to make a sales report after this while loop and I have to calculate the total amount of sales for each item. How do I do that since the numbers are random and the loop repeats itself depending on the number of customers?

```
while (CustomersSimulated <= MaxCustomersSimulated)
        {   
                    //customer number
        System.out.println("Customer " + CustomersSimulated);    


                //one random item for each customer     
    Random RandomList = new Random();
    int RandomItem = RandomList.nextInt(4) + 1;   

    if (RandomItem == 1)
        {
        System.out.println("Item purchased: Coffee");
        final double CoffeePrice = 1.50;

                          //random quantity for the item        
        Random RandomListTwo = new Random();    
        int RandomQuantity = RandomListTwo.nextInt(5) + 1;
        System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + RandomQuantity);

                          //total cost for the one customer     
        double TotalCoffeeCost = RandomQuantity * CoffeePrice;  
        System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + NumberFormat.format(TotalCoffeeCost)); 
        }
    else if (RandomItem == 2)
        {
        System.out.println("Item purchased: Latte");
        final double LattePrice = 3.50;

        Random RandomListTwo = new Random();
        int RandomQuantity = RandomListTwo.nextInt(5) + 1;
        System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + RandomQuantity);

        double TotalLatteCost = RandomQuantity * LattePrice; 
        System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + NumberFormat.format(TotalLatteCost));
        }
    else if (RandomItem == 3)
        {
        System.out.println("Item purchased: Cappuccino");
        final double CappuccinoPrice = 3.25;

        Random RandomListTwo = new Random();
        int RandomQuantity = RandomListTwo.nextInt(5) + 1;
        System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + RandomQuantity);

        double TotalCappuccinoCost = RandomQuantity * CappuccinoPrice; 
        System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + NumberFormat.format(TotalCappuccinoCost));
        }
    else if (RandomItem == 4)
        {
        System.out.println("Item purchased: Espresso");
        final double EspressoPrice = 2.00;

        Random RandomListTwo = new Random();
        int RandomQuantity = RandomListTwo.nextInt(5) + 1;
        System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + RandomQuantity);

        double TotalEspressoCost = RandomQuantity * EspressoPrice; 
        System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + NumberFormat.format(TotalEspressoCost));
        }

    System.out.println(" ");

    CustomersSimulated++;
    }
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried). (Hint: you probably need several counters.)

Comment: I tried a for statement within the while loop, but that didn't work out cause I don't know how to add the costs together instead of how many times a customer bought that certain item.

Comment: Please post the code so that we can help you. If you know, for example, that customers bought 5 lattes, what was the cost for the lattes? How did you calculate that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I would answer it. Like @IswantoSan said, `NumberFormat.format()` does not compile so I changed that. Also, I got rid of all of the re-initialization that occurs every time you go through the loop. It is unneeded. Doesn't take up that much more memory but I was always told it is good practice. Also, the first letter in variable names should be lower case. Again, I was always told that is good practice. I could be wrong.

I hope this is what you were looking for.

```
final static double espressoPrice = 2.00;
final static double cappuccinoPrice = 3.25;
final static double lattePrice = 3.50;
final static double coffeePrice = 1.50;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int customersSimulated = 0;
    int maxCustomersSimulated = 4;
    int randomQuantity = 0;
    double total = 0;

    double totalCoffee = 0;
    double totalCappuccino = 0;
    double totalLatte = 0;
    double totalEspresso = 0;

    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");

    while (customersSimulated <= maxCustomersSimulated) { 

        System.out.println("Customer " + customersSimulated);    

        Random randomList = new Random();
        int randomItem = randomList.nextInt(4) + 1;   

        if (randomItem == 1) {

            System.out.println("Item purchased: Coffee");
            randomQuantity = randomList.nextInt(5) + 1;
            System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + randomQuantity);
            double totalCoffeeCost = randomQuantity * coffeePrice;
            System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + df.format(totalCoffeeCost)); 

            totalCoffee+=totalCoffeeCost;
        } else if (randomItem == 2) {

            System.out.println("Item purchased: Latte");
            randomQuantity = randomList.nextInt(5) + 1;
            System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + randomQuantity);
            double totalLatteCost = randomQuantity * lattePrice; 
            System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + df.format(totalLatteCost));

            totalLatte+=totalLatteCost;
        } else if (randomItem == 3) {

            System.out.println("Item purchased: Cappuccino");
            randomQuantity = randomList.nextInt(5) + 1;
            System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + randomQuantity);
            double totalCappuccinoCost = randomQuantity * cappuccinoPrice; 
            System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + df.format(totalCappuccinoCost));

            totalCappuccino+=totalCappuccinoCost;
        } else if (randomItem == 4) {

            System.out.println("Item purchased: Espresso");
            randomQuantity = randomList.nextInt(5) + 1;
            System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + randomQuantity);
            double totalEspressoCost = randomQuantity * espressoPrice; 
            System.out.println("Total Cost: $" + df.format(totalEspressoCost));

            totalEspresso+=totalEspressoCost;
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Total Coffee Cost: $" + totalCoffee);
        System.out.println("Total Cappuccino Cost: $" + totalCappuccino);
        System.out.println("Total Llatte Cost: $" + totalLatte);
        System.out.println("Total Espresso Cost: $" + totalEspresso);
        System.out.println();

        customersSimulated++;
    }
}
```

Basically, when you initialize and define a variable outside that while loop, `+=` it within the loop, it can be accessed outside the loop and will be "remembered" throughout the code being ran; if that makes sense to you.

Comment: I see. Thanks. This looks a lot easier than the accumulator I was trying to fit in.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to create four different counters and store each sale by adding it each time.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a global variable for each of the items and increment the value anytime it's selected inside those if-else statements. that way, no matter what is chosen at random, the global variable will be incremented. you can just total it all up later depending on the price. I hope that's what you were looking for.

Comment: The variables don't need to be "global" (or more accurately member or class variables), they can just as easily be local variables if they are only used in the same method as the OP posted.

Comment: you are absolutely right. Thank you for pointing that out. DERP!

Answer (score 0):

Like the other said, create a new counter variable outside your loop to store the total.

See this:

```
        double TotalAllCoffeeCost = 0;
        double TotalAllLatteCost = 0;
        double TotalAllCappuccinoCost = 0;
        double TotalAllEspressoCost = 0;
        while (CustomersSimulated <= MaxCustomersSimulated) {
            // customer number
            System.out.println("Customer " + CustomersSimulated);

            // one random item for each customer
            Random RandomList = new Random();
            int RandomItem = RandomList.nextInt(4) + 1;

            if (RandomItem == 1) {
                System.out.println("Item purchased: Coffee");
                final double CoffeePrice = 1.50;

                // random quantity for the item
                Random RandomListTwo = new Random();
                int RandomQuantity = RandomListTwo.nextInt(5) + 1;
                System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + RandomQuantity);

                // total cost for the one customer
                double TotalCoffeeCost = RandomQuantity * CoffeePrice;
                TotalAllCoffeeCost+=TotalCoffeeCost;
                System.out.println("Total Cost: $"
                        + new DecimalFormat().format(TotalCoffeeCost));
            } else if (RandomItem == 2) {
                System.out.println("Item purchased: Latte");
                final double LattePrice = 3.50;

                Random RandomListTwo = new Random();
                int RandomQuantity = RandomListTwo.nextInt(5) + 1;
                System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + RandomQuantity);

                double TotalLatteCost = RandomQuantity * LattePrice;
                TotalAllLatteCost+=TotalLatteCost;
                System.out.println("Total Cost: $"
                        + new DecimalFormat().format(TotalLatteCost));
            } else if (RandomItem == 3) {
                System.out.println("Item purchased: Cappuccino");
                final double CappuccinoPrice = 3.25;

                Random RandomListTwo = new Random();
                int RandomQuantity = RandomListTwo.nextInt(5) + 1;
                System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + RandomQuantity);

                double TotalCappuccinoCost = RandomQuantity * CappuccinoPrice;
                TotalAllCappuccinoCost+=TotalCappuccinoCost;
                System.out.println("Total Cost: $"
                        + new DecimalFormat().format(TotalCappuccinoCost));
            } else if (RandomItem == 4) {
                System.out.println("Item purchased: Espresso");
                final double EspressoPrice = 2.00;

                Random RandomListTwo = new Random();
                int RandomQuantity = RandomListTwo.nextInt(5) + 1;
                System.out.println("Quantity purchased: " + RandomQuantity);

                double TotalEspressoCost = RandomQuantity * EspressoPrice;
                TotalAllEspressoCost+=TotalEspressoCost;
                System.out.println("Total Cost: $"
                        + new DecimalFormat().format(TotalEspressoCost));
            }

            System.out.println(" ");

            System.out.println("Total Cofee Cost : " + new DecimalFormat().format(TotalAllCoffeeCost));
            System.out.println("Total Latte Cost : " + new DecimalFormat().format(TotalAllLatteCost));
            System.out.println("Total Cappucino Cost : " + new DecimalFormat().format(TotalAllCappuccinoCost));
            System.out.println("Total Espresso Cost : " + new DecimalFormat().format(TotalAllEspressoCost));

            CustomersSimulated++;
        }
```

Anyway, your code :

```
NumberFormat.format(...)
```

doesn't compiled because [format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#format%28long,%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29) is not static method.